# Python script output in geometry nodes

Tags: python, geometry-nodes

Is it possible to generate a bunch of strings inside a python script, then use the ouput of the script inside geometry node ?

Comment: Sure, simply add some "String" nodes to the node tree, using Python. Or fill existing node(s) with Python.

Comment: That can be. But could you elaborate a bit more about the string usage inside gn (as if not several possibilities to do it, and it depends of your use case)?

Comment: well, i'd like to make a name generator inside python since i'm starting to get used to it. Then use those strings inside geometry nodes to create curves.
Those curves are then converted to gcode and printed with an axidraw (that part is already done)

Comment: and what do you mean markus by "filling existing nodes with python ?" I'm new to coding inside blender

Comment: ok, but one string = one object having a gn modifier? Or other?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's an example: set the geonodes string to my last answer on BSE:

```py
import requests, re
from bpy import data as D

response = requests.get(
    'https://api.stackexchange.com/2.3/users/60486/answers',
    params={
        'site':'blender.stackexchange',
        'pagesize': 1,
        'filter': 'withbody'
    }
)
response.raise_for_status()
html = response.json()['items'][0]['body']
pattern = re.compile(r'<[^>]*>')
plain_text = re.sub(pattern, '', html)

# the answer:
D.node_groups['My geonode tree'].nodes['String'].string = plain_text
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: So i tweaked it a bit for it ot work on my blender, but do you have any idea on how can i stock each generated text as a single instance ?

Comment: @DoanFARON if you had that in the question, I probably would address it in the answer :P