Geo Nodes: Read a CSV text spreadsheet and input said text into String node
I'm looking for a way to import text from spreadsheet into a String node input (or into the textbox).
I found there are many ways of imputing coordinates or numerical values, but not text.
How can it be done?
Example:
CSV text:
Column 1   Column 2   Column 3
Well,      Hello      There.

Blender output in String nodes:
Well, Hello There.

Something like this but using CSV instead of REST API? https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/309561/60486

Yes, actually. {more text}
